# How can I properly kill a celery task in a kubernetes environment?

Tags: python, kubernetes, containers, celery

How can I properly kill celery tasks running on containers inside a kubernetes environment? The structure of the whole application (all written in Python) is as follows:

1. A SDK that makes requests to our API;
2. A Kubernetes structure with one pod running the API and other pods running celery containers to deal with some long-running tasks that can be triggered by the API. These celery containers autoscale.

Suppose we call a SDK method that in turn makes a request to the API that triggers a task to be run on a celery container. What would be the correct/graceful way to kill this task if need be? I am aware that celery tasks have a `revoke()` method, but I tried using this approach and it did not work, even using `terminate=True` and `signal=signal.SIGKILL` (maybe this has something to do with the fact that I am using Azure Service Bus as a broker?)

Perhaps a mapping between a celery task and its corresponding container name would help, but I could not find a way to get this information as well.

Any help and/or ideas would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: can I ask why do you want to revoke/terminate the task? is it due to applicative reason (like a non-relevant task) or architecture constraint?

Comment: It is due to tasks that might get stuck and/or the user wants to cancel its execution

Comment: can you add your efforts? the revoke code snippet that you tried?

Comment: Terribly sorry for the belated answer, @ItayB. I found a solution using a file that is shared among the API and celery containers. I describe it in more details in my answer below. Nonetheless, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to write to file shared by both API and Celery containers. In this file, whenever an interruption is captured, a flag is set to `true`. Inside the celery containers I keep periodically checking the contents of such file. If the flag is set to `true`, then I gracefully clear things up and raise an error.