# Purge Celery tasks on GCP K8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, celery

I want to purge Celery tasks. Celery is running on GCP Kubernetes in my case. Is there a way to do it from terminal? For example via `kubectl`?

Answer (score 0):

> The solution I found was to write to file shared by both API and
> Celery containers. In this file, whenever an interruption is captured,
> a flag is set to true. Inside the celery containers I keep
> periodically checking the contents of such file. If the flag is set to
> true, then I gracefully clear things up and raise an error.

Does this solve your problem? [How can I properly kill a celery task in a kubernetes environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799974/how-can-i-properly-kill-a-celery-task-in-a-kubernetes-environment)

an alternate solution may be:

```
$ celery -A proj purge
```

or

```
from proj.celery import app
app.control.purge()
```